# Wordpress: When I click in the blog link then it redirect me to home page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website www.xyz.com and in that I have a link Blog.

When user click on Blog link, then user is redirected to www.xyz.com/wordpress.

Inside www.xyz.com/wordpress i have several blogs links, but when I click on any blog link it throws "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Below is .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Anybody knows what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: what do you mean several blogs? you have wp-MU ?

Comment: All pages go to the home page or only blog pages?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen On the home page I have several links, when I click on the link it will give me "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: @KrupalPanchal no it did not go anywhere it gives me "The requested URL was not found on this server." when I click on any link.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the default `.htaccess` and check.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I tried above code in .htacess but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file does't have any problem. it's better to check theme php codes to make sure if the link redirects to homepage there or not. when you check that code, it should be like below:

```
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>">
// your post content
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the above issue by updating xyz.com.conf file with below codes:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin admin@xyz.com
ServerName xyz.com
ServerAlias www.xyz.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz.com_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz.com_access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```